# html form not working

Tags: html, forms

I have a page generated with php. I copied the code from another working page and inside I have:

```
echo "<center><form name='login_data23' method='post' action='fck_nuovo_documenti.php'><table border='1' rules='rows' width='1040'>";
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td width='400' valign='top'><input type='text' name='titolo' size='25' maxlength='30' value='titolo nuovo documento'/></td>";
echo "<td width='400' valign='top'></td>";
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'>
<button type='submit' name='submit' title='Inserisci nuovo documento pdf' value='pdf'><img src='./img/icona_pdf.png' /></button></td>";
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'><button type='submit' name='submit' title='Inserisci nuovo documento' value='html'><img src='./img/icona_nuovo.png' /></button></td>";
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'></td><td width='40' valign='top'>";  
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'></td>";  
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'></td>";
echo "<td width='40' valign='top'></td>"; 
echo "</tr></table></form><table border='1' rules='rows' width='1040'>";
```

The page is correctly displayed but once you press one button of the form it only seems that the page reloads. 
On the page where I got it, it is working perfectly...

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Use `<input type="submit" />`.

Comment: Did you tested if it reaches the target? Put an <? var_dump($_POST); exit; ?> on fck_nuovo_documenti.php.

Comment: I had a problem with that using IE. I once had 2 <input type 'submit'> with two different values but at the receiver page IE didn't got the difference.
The problem is that according to the pressed button I must have two different values: and the system must be compatible with every browser due to the users target.


I'll try with the var_dump

Comment: maybe you had nested forms so it didn't work properly. <input type="submit" /> works on every browser.

Comment: no, it doesn't reach the operative page...
@DavorMlinaric it does, but I had problems reading the value.. I don't remember which IE version but if I had pressed no matter which submit I received always a null value. After a short research on the web, someone suggested using two buttons in order to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `<button type="submit">` as everyone's saying and if you having problems with `<input type="submit">` you can just use JavaScript, our saviour:

1- Create an id tag to your form with any id you want.

2- Create an hidden field that will hold your option (html or pdf).

3- Create a function to submit to form:

```
function doForm(option) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = option;
    document.getElementByid('formId').submit();
}
```

4- Then, use the buttons to submit the form:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doForm(1)" /> // or 
<input type="button" onclick="doForm(2)" />
```

Treat that option in your PHP code.

**NOTE:** This is just a workaround if you can't do this with standard html objects.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :) 

I really have to learn javascript... it's not the first time it saves my web pages

Comment: Javascript: People hates, but it saves! =P

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML issues right off the bat. You might want to consider the following approach:

```
// end of PHP CODE
?>

<center>
    <form name="login_data23" method="post" action="fck_nuovo_documenti.php">
        <table border="1" rules="rows" width="1040">
            <tr>
                <td width="400" valign="top">
                    <input type="text" name="titolo" size="25" maxlength="30" value="titolo nuovo documento" />
                </td>
                <td width="400" valign="top"></td>
                <td width="40" valign="top">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" title="Inserisci nuovo documento pdf" value="pdf">
                        <img src="./img/icona_pdf.png" />
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td width="40" valign="top">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" title="Inserisci nuovo documento" value="html">
                        <img src="./img/icona_nuovo.png" />
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
                <!-- <td width="40" valign="top"> no closing tag -->
                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>

<?php

// beginning of PHP code
```

I see your submit button but you need to make sure the path to your file is correct. `fck_nuovo_documenti.php` means `./fck_nuovo_documenti.php`. In plain English this means *this* directory has `fck_nuovo_documenti.php`. You can check to make sure that php file is actually getting data by looking at what is received from the POST action. Just pick an input field to look at and see what comes up.

```
<?php echo $_POST['titolo']; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the clean code but no success... the bad thing is that I am out of ideas... the target page exist and works fine... 
but I can't get the first page to send the informations x.x